# Deleting from SQLlite3 in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter

I new to coding and trying to delete a user ID from a SQLite db. I have googled and watched hours of videos trying to find a way to get this code to work. Please help. I am writing in Python 3.X on a raspberry Pi and using tkinter for the GUI. My database has 4 columns (first_name, last_name, user_id and password). The password_delete function sets up the screen to get the input and the delete_funtion is supposed to delete the user id entered in. currently I am having trouble passing the user_id variable between the two functions. Once the variable is passed over, will the delete function work?  Thank you very much for the help.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x700')

def delete_function():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('instructor_db.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    
    user_id_delete = password_delete()
    print(user_id_delete)
    
    delete_variable = """DELETE FROM instructors WHERE user_id = ?"""
    c.execute(delete_variable,(user_id_delete, ))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def password_delete():
    password_delete_screen = LabelFrame(root, width=500, height=700)
    password_delete_screen.pack()
    password_delete_screen.propagate(0)
    
    user_id_lbl = Label(password_delete_screen, text = "User Name").grid(row=0, column=0)
    
    global user_id_delete
    
    user_id_delete = Entry(password_delete_screen).grid(row=0, column=1)
    
    log_in_btn = Button(password_delete_screen, text = "Delete User", command = delete_function)
    log_in_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
    

password_delete()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have a common mistake asked many times in SO on the following line:

```py
user_id_delete = Entry(password_delete_screen).grid(row=0, column=1)
```

`user_id_delete` is None because it is the result of `grid(...)`, not `Entry(...)`.  You need to split it into two lines:

```py
user_id_delete = Entry(password_delete_screen)
user_id_delete.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

And for your question, you can simply pass the input content into `delete_function()` directly instead of using global variable:

```py
def delete_function(user_id_delete):
    if user_id_delete:
        conn = sqlite3.connect('instructor_db.db')
        c = conn.cursor()

        delete_variable = """DELETE FROM instructors WHERE user_id = ?"""
        c.execute(delete_variable, (user_id_delete,))
        if c.rowcount:
            print('User deleted:', user_id_delete)
        else:
            print('User not found:', user_id_delete)

        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
    else:
        print('User input is empty')

def password_delete():
    password_delete_screen = LabelFrame(root, width=500, height=700)
    password_delete_screen.pack()
    password_delete_screen.propagate(0)

    Label(password_delete_screen, text = "User Name").grid(row=0, column=0)

    user_id_delete = Entry(password_delete_screen)
    user_id_delete.grid(row=0, column=1)

    log_in_btn = Button(password_delete_screen, text = "Delete User",
                        command=lambda: delete_function(user_id_delete.get()))
    log_in_btn.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)
```